# how to select data between 2 dates

Tags: php

I have table for tasks list.

I usually use linux time to set the dates but this time I tried DATE type.

how can I select all the task that their targetDate is in 2 days or less?

I know how to do it in the SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks 
WHERE `targetDate` >= CURDATE() 
  AND `targetDate`  < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

**I would like it know how to do it in the PHP code**

```
id  int(10) 
title   varchar(250)    utf8_general_ci
text    text    utf8_general_ci
catID   tinyint(3)  
createUserID    int(4)  
createDate  date    
targetDate  date
```

Comment: You need to connect to MySQL database and use 'mysqli_query'.

Comment: Your data is in a database... like Pupil said... you have to connect to and query the database for your data using either `mysqli_` or more preferably `pdo_mysql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE targetDate BETWEEN '2015-10-13' AND '2015-10-27'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE DATE_FORMAT(targetDate,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2015-10-13' AND '2015-10-27'
```

Answer (score 0):

your Date type in `SQL` is in `"YYYY-MM-DD"` format. So in your query, you have to give the `same format` to grab the data you wanted.

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BETWEEN` CLAUSE in combination with date_sub( now( ) , `INTERVAL 2 DAY ) AND NOW( )`

```
SELECT * FROM tasks 
WHERE
targetDate BETWEEN date_sub( now( ) , INTERVAL 2 DAY ) AND NOW( )
```

Answer (score 0):

use mysql `CURDATE()` or `INTERVAL`

```
SELECT * FROM tasks 
WHERE
targetDate BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY ) and CURDATE()
```