# How do I do a query where the time differece is 1 day

Tags: mysql

How would I make it so that I can search a table and get the values where the date difference equals 1

an example of what I want to do is

```
SELECT * FROM table where DATEDIFF('2006-04-01','2006-03-01') = 1
```

I found this but I don't know how to implement it or if there is a better way. Still looking.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2006-04-01','2006-03-01')
```

also found:

```
SELECT OrderId,DATE_SUB(2014-11-22 13:23:44.657,INTERVAL 5 DAY) AS SubtractDate
FROM Orders
```

but I want to get a result when the time difference between both dates is 1

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this as follows:

```
SELECT OrderId,DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS SubtractDate
FROM Orders;
```

Now () : For today's date
INTERVAL 1 DAY : For you need to get data with one day difference

Or you can see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633653/mysql-date-subnow-interval-1-day-24-hours-or-weekday)

OR `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE DATE(lastModified) = DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) );`

You can see more methods [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342582/how-to-select-data-between-2-dates/33342797#33342797)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a select where the diff is one day ..

```
select * from my_table 
where datediff(my_date1, my_date2) =1
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer from scaisEdge

If  you want to take the time into account, and thus only get records with a difference of exactly 24 hours (86400 seconds)

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(my_date1, my_date2)) = 86400
```